# Going down in history

Tags: riddle, word

> I start my day purring
>
> And end it among the foundations
>
> All in all, this trip will go down in history

The sought solution is a single word.

Elaboration / explanations preferred, as well as some patience since this is my first attempt at a puzzle and it might be terrible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> a [**catabasis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katabasis).

I start my day purring

> **Cat**, as found by Mick O'Hea.

And end it among the foundations

> A **basis** is a foundation.

All in all, this trip will go down in history

> A **catabasis** is a downward trip.

Comment: Well done! I'm glad somebody was able to find it without hints.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is

> **Caterpillar**

I start my day purring

> **Cat**

And end it among the foundations

> **Pillar**

All in all, this trip will go down in history

> I don't know this one...

Comment: Ooh, nice one! (And thank you for replying) unfortunately it's not the answer.

Comment: Though this answer is already stated as wrong, the trip going down in history could have been explained as (rot13)gur ohggresyl rssrpg

Answer (score 6):

Having previously wrongly guessed,

> catacombs

I'm editing this to suggest

> [catafalque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catafalque)

I start my day purring

> begins with cat

And end it among the foundations

> End up buried after the funeral

All in all, this trip will go down in history

> A catafalque is usually used for the lying in state/funeral of a distinguished person, which would be a historically significant event

Comment: Not it, but closer than you might think! (And thank you for answering)

Comment: Changed it a bit, pretty sure it's still wrong though!

Comment: That's a gorgeous word, I wish I could upvote your answer twice! ...it's also still not correct. But you're right that the solution is not an everyday word...

Comment: +2 for trying to upvote twice!

Answer (score 6):

Mostly not the answer but will try

> Catalog or Catalogue

I start my day purring

> Cat

And end it among the foundations

> Log, used in foundations

All in all, this trip will go down in history

> One of the synonyms of catalog is archive, which is meant to go down in History.

Comment: Ooh, very nice! And also not it. (and thank you)